# How to add content to every site and page on nginx

Tags: nginx

I need to add a piece of content to every page of every website in my control (due to GDPR). In IIS, I created a custom module, loaded in the server GAC, and added a single line to each sites' web.config. I'm now trying to do the same thing on a LEMP stack.

The message and interface are exactly the same for every site, so the preferred solution should read content from a single file on the server and append to the end of every  tag. The addition_module `add_after_body` seems like the closest thing to what I want to do. A small negative is that it needs to be inside the `location` block, so the solution will need to be replicated on every site; but the bigger negative is that `add_after_body` goes to a URI and not a file, so every site would need to have the same file.

I also tried.

```
add_after_body http://localhost/gdprmessage.html;
```

but that resulted in a 404 message being included on each page.

Is there a way to append content on every page on every site on the server?

If not, using nginx include, I can minimize the changes to each sites' conf, but how can I append content that can be maintained in a single location?

Answer (score 0):

The `add_after_body` directive can be placed within a `location` block, or the surrounding `server` block, or even the surrounding `http` block. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_addition_module.html#add_after_body) for details.

However, it does appear that the URI needs to be a local location, and cannot accept a *scheme* or *hostname*.

As you suggest, the simplest solution would be to `include` a file into each `server` block, containing (for example):

```
add_after_body /gdprmessage.html;
location = /gdprmessage.html {
    root /path/to/common/file;
}
```